# PHPMailer send email with "CSS3 content"

Tags: php, css, codeigniter, email

I'm using PHPMailer with Codeigniter to send an email. But in my web Browser, the page look fine, and when it comes to the email, it's ripped some of my style, such as `transform` and `position:fixed`

Here's some of my style code :

```
.arrow-atas {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-top: 70px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 70px solid transparent;
    border-left: 70px solid yellow;

    margin-left: -11px;
    z-index: 10;
    margin-top: -46px;
    position: fixed;
    transform: rotate(225deg);
}
```

And when I inspect my email style. This what I got[image]

It's ripped off some of my `style` code.. Can I make the style still available to the email ?

Comment: Are you looking to have `CSS3` code in an email? a lot of email browsers dont support CSS3 - https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/

Comment: Yeah @Andrew , I'm looking to embed `CCS3` code in an email.. I'm using Inbox by Google. So, I don't have any choice to make that code working ?